# 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an update form, whem i press updated for the form to update the user profile it I get the error "'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'id'"

my models is:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="custom_user_profile", primary_key=True)

   organization = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True) 
   address_line_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
   address_line_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
   state = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
   post_code = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.user.username


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile, new = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

and my views is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from user_profile.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from forms import UserProfileForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required 
def update_profile(request):
    userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    form = UserProfileForm(initial={

        'organization':userProfile.organization,
        'address_line_1':userProfile.address_line_1,
        'address_line_2':userProfile.address_line_2,
        'city':userProfile.city,
        'state':userProfile.state,
        'post_code':userProfile.post_code,
        'country':userProfile.country,
      })
    return render_to_response('user_profile/update_profile.html', {'form':form}, RequestContext(request))


@login_required 
def profile(request, profile_id):
    if profile_id == "0":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    else:
        userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=profile_id)

    return render_to_response('user_profile/profile.html', {'userProfile':userProfile}, RequestContext(request))


@login_required 
def send_update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)


            organization = form.cleaned_data['organization']
            userProfile.organization = organization

            address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
            userProfile.address_line_1 = address_line_1

            address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
            userProfile.address_line_2 = address_line_2

            city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            userProfile.city = city

            state = form.cleaned_data['state']
            userProfile.state = state

            post_code = form.cleaned_data['post_code']
            userProfile.post_code = post_code

            country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            userProfile.country = country

            userProfile.save()
            return redirect('/user/profile/' + str(userProfile.id))

        else:
            form = UserProfileForm()

        return redirect('/user/send_update_profile/')
```

I can not work out why. One thing is that in admin.py, if i try to add 'id' as list display. An error occurs saying that there is no id in the user profile I am creating. Though, i thought an id field is automatically created when a model is created.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Normally there is but you've specifically overridden that by defining user as the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django gives each model an [automatic primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) named `id`, unless you specify a primary key yourself. In your case, your model does not have an `id` field, because you have made `user` the primary key.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="custom_user_profile", primary_key=True)
```

You could change the code to use the `userProfile.user_id`. Another option is to use the [pk shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut) to access the primary key.

```
return redirect('/user/profile/' + str(userProfile.pk))
```